# Is there a decomposition/structural theorem for 3-edge-connected graphs?

Tags: graphs

A graph is 2-edge-connected if and only if it has a closed ear decomposition.

I am looking for such a theorem for the **3**-edge-connected case. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find one. Is there something like this in the literature?

Comment: This is a trivial statement: "A graph is 3-edge-connected if and only if for every edge $e \in E$, $G - \{e\}$ has a closed ear decomposition"

Comment: I don't want trivial statements, I want structural theorems. To give another example of the type of theorem I want:
A graph $G$ is 3(-vertex)-connected if and only if there exists a sequence $G_0, \dots, G_k$ of graphs such that $G_0 = K_4$ and $G_{i+1}$ has an edge $uv$ such that $G_i = G_{i+1}/uv$, $d(u) \geq 3$ and $d(v) \geq 3$ for every $i < k$. (Moreover, the graphs in any such sequence are all 3(-vertex)-connected.)

Comment: As a side note, I forgot $G = G_k$ in the above comment. 

As there appears to be no such theorem, it would be an interesting result in itself. There are structural theorems for 3-connected graphs, why not prove something in this direction for 3-edge-connected ones? The question arose while we were trying to prove something for dual graphs of simple planar graphs, which are 3-edge-connected.

Comment: You can check out the results on _exact_ or _uniform_ $k$-edge connected graphs for $k=3$ by both Kingsford and Marçais (2009) and Göring, Hofmann, and Streicher (2022).